# How can I rewrite .then notation to an async function for aesthetic reasons in react

Tags: javascript

I've this original code:

```js
fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((playlistData) => {
    let playlists = playlistData.items;
    let trackDataPromises = playlists.map((playlist) => {
      let responsePromise = fetch(playlist.tracks.href, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
        },
      });
      let trackDataPromise = responsePromise.then((response) =>
        response.json()
      );
      return trackDataPromise;
    });
    let allTracksDataPromises = Promise.all(trackDataPromises);
    let playlistsPromise = allTracksDataPromises.then((trackDatas) => {
      trackDatas.forEach((trackData, i) => {
        playlists[i].trackDatas = trackData.items
          .map((item) => item.track)
          .map((trackData) => ({
            name: trackData.name,
            duration: trackData.duration_ms / 1000,
          }));
      });
      return playlists;
    });
    return playlistsPromise;
  })
  .then((playlists) =>
    this.setState({
      playlists: playlists.map((item) => {
        return {
          name: item.name,
          id: item.id,
          imageUrl: item.images[0].url,
          songs: item.trackDatas.slice(0, 3),
          uri: item.uri,
        };
      }),
    })
  )
  .catch((err) => console.error(err + " playlistData"));
```

The works but I wanted to wrote it because it's messy and I wanted to write it in an async function form.
So I tried this:

```js
const fetchPlaylist = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
  });
  const playlistData = await response.json();
  const playlists = playlistData.items;
  let trackDataPromises = playlists.map((item) => {
    const trackhref = async () => {
      const tracksResponse = await fetch(item.tracks.href, {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
      });
      return tracksResponse.json();
    };
    return trackhref();
  });
  Promise.all(trackDataPromises).then((trackDatas) => {
    trackDatas.forEach((trackData, i) => {
      playlists[i].trackDatas = trackData.items
        .map((item) => item.track)
        .map((trackData) => ({
          name: trackData.name,
          duration: trackData.duration_ms / 1000,
        }));
    });
    return playlists;
  });
  return;
};
fetchPlaylist()
  .then((playlists) =>
    this.setState({
      playlists: playlists.map((item) => {
        return {
          name: item.name,
          id: item.id,
          imageUrl: item.images[0].url,
          songs: item.trackDatas.slice(0, 3),
          uri: item.uri,
        };
      }),
    })
  )
  .catch((err) => console.error(err + " playlistData"));
```

The new code doesn't work... The react complier says that "can't map undefined" while pointing at this line. `playlists: playlists.map((item)` I'm not sure what's happening here because `item` is definitely defined.

Comment: fetchPlaylist *explicitly* returns a promise of undefined. Note you can await Promise.all, and trackhref can be factored out entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, nothing is usually given the value of `undefined`. If you don't pass an argument to a function then that argument will have the value of `undefined`. Similarly if you return nothing it means you are returning `undefined`.

Here you are deliberately returning nothing:

```
    return playlists;
  });
  return;  // <-------- this returns undefined
};
```

Therefore the return value of `fetchPlaylist()` is `undefined` and you cannot `map` an undefined value.

You need to return the result of `Promise.all()` instead:

```
  // Return this:
  return Promise.all(trackDataPromises).then((trackDatas) => {
    trackDatas.forEach((trackData, i) => {
      playlists[i].trackDatas = trackData.items
        .map((item) => item.track)
        .map((trackData) => ({
          name: trackData.name,
          duration: trackData.duration_ms / 1000,
        }));
    });
    return playlists;
  });
};
```